# echo class "active" - if class="" is already exists or not.

Tags: php, html, css

The following PHP function add class="active" to the current page open.

```
<?php #add class .active to current page
   $directoryURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   $path = parse_url($directoryURL, PHP_URL_PATH);
   $components = explode('/', $path);
   $currentPage = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", end($components));

   if ($currentPage == "") {
       $currentPage = "index";
   }

   function href($url) {
      global $currentPage;
      $path = explode('/', $url);
      $page = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", end($path));
      echo 'href="' . $url . '"';

      if ($page == $currentPage) {
         echo 'active';
      }
   }
?>
```

Here is the menu items:

```
<li><a class="icon-glass"<?php href('index.php');?>>Home</a></li>
<li><a <?php href('about.php');?>>About</a></li>
```

The problem is, that function only works with menu items that has no class="" declared, i.e:

```
<li><a <?php href('about.php');?>>About</a></li>
```

And it does not work for this one:

```
<li><a class="icon-glass"<?php href('index.php');?>>Home</a></li>
```

I believe it is something to do with this part of the script:

```
if ($page == $currentPage) {
   echo 'class="active"';
}
```

The question: How do I keep it do what it does now, which is adding `class=""` when it is not already added, BUT also just add the `.active` bit inside an already existed class (if found)?

I tried to only use `echo 'active';` but that didn't work.

Comment: try `return` instead of `echo`

Comment: after changing it to return did you change php code to `echo href('index.php')` in `<a>`.

Comment: Try to `echo` the function now.

Comment: Oh, Krishna beat me to it :P

Comment: @krishna sorry didn't really know what you mean? the class class="icon-glass" in the index has to stay :/

Comment: change this `<li><a class="icon-glass"<?php href('index.php');?>>Home</a></li>` to `<li><a class="icon-glass"<?php echo href('index.php');?>>Home</a></li>`

Comment: note: echo added before href

Answer (score 0):

Try this format with existing php code

```
<li><a class="icon-glass <?php href('index.php');?>">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="<?php href('about.php');?>">About</a></li>
```

Means you have to echo the class active inside class property double quotes "".

Comment: It made the HTML like: <a class="icon-glass href=" index.php"class="active" "="">Home</a>

Answer (score 0):

Replace function href with

```
function href($url) {
    global $currentPage;
    $path = explode('/', $url);
    $page = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", end($path));

    if ($page == $currentPage) {
        echo ' active " ';
    }else{
        echo ' " ';
    }
    echo ' href="' . $url . '" ';
```

}

And this html

```
<li><a class="icon-glass"<?php href('index.php');?>>Home</a></li>
<li><a <?php href('about.php');?>>About</a></li>
```

with

```
<li><a class="icon-glass <?php href('index.php');?>>Home</a></li>
<li><a class="<?php href('about.php');?>>About</a></li>
```

Comment: Is this however a good and reliable way to do it? as you are adding the HREF inside the class

Comment: Href is not inside class look the output class is already closed have a look @ this codeif ($page == $currentPage) {
        echo ' active " ';
    }else{
        echo ' " ';
    }   class is always closed if we are adding active or not with the help of if else.